# NSPredicate(Swift) : SUBQUERY not working

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, core-data, nspredicate

I have two model like below:

```
class Topic : NSObject {

    var subTopics : [SubTopic]!
    var topicId : Int!
    var topicName : String!


class SubTopic : NSObject {

    var subTopicDesc : String!
    var subTopicDescText : String!
    var subTopicId : Int!
    var subTopicName : String!
}
```

and array of Topic defined in my viewcontroller :

```
var rightsDataArray: [Topic] = []
```

And here is my Search logic :

```
let pred = NSPredicate(format: "topicName CONTAINS %@ OR SUBQUERY(subTopics, $SubTopics, $SubTopics.subTopicDescText CONTAINS %@).@count > 0 OR SUBQUERY(subTopics, $SubTopics, $SubTopics.subTopicName CONTAINS %@).@count > 0",searchBar.text!,searchBar.text!,searchBar.text!)
let filteredArray =  (self.rightsDataArray as NSArray).filtered(using: pred)
```

And here is the result if search string is Health:

[image]

If the searchedText is present in subTopic[0], then I want to remove subTopic[1],subTopic[2],subTopic[3] from resulting subTopics Array, and only retrieve subTopic[0].

Comment: The image links for 2 and 3 are not working.

Comment: Not actually image just an array.

Comment: Got it, now I understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

You are filtering the top level `Topic` array, and nothing in you code will touch the subTopics subarray.  The predicate is deciding whether or not to add a particular `Topic` (the top level object) to the filtered array based on its subTopics. But once a Topic matches the criteria (ie having at least one subTopic that has the search terms) the `Topic` is added.

It seems like you want to modify the `Topic`'s `subTopics` array to contains less objects.  For that you have to iterate through every `Topic` and modify it's  `subTopics` property.